# Combine results from array of objects based on key in nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have array of objects where I want to filter and combine results based on specific id. This is example:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        items: [
            {
                id: 10,
                values: [11],
            },
            {
                id: 20,
                values: [13, 14, 15],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        items: [
            {
                id: 10,
                values: [12],
            },
            {
                id: 20,
                values: [13, 15],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

And this is expected result:

```
[
    {
        id: 10,
        values: [11, 12],
    },
    {
        id: 20,
        values: [13, 14, 15],
    },
];
```

I also need to filter duplicates. Thanks

Note: What if I want this result?

```
[
    {
        // here I want value for id 10 (it will be always one number)
        value: 11,
        // here I want values for id 20 (array of numbers) => remove possible duplicates
        values: [13, 14, 15],
    },
    {
        // here I want value for id 10 (it will be always one number)
        value: 12,
        // here I want values for id 20 (array of numbers) => remove possible duplicates
        values: [13, 15],
    },
];
```

I tried the same approach with Map, but without success. Basically I want to combine values based on ids.

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212).

Comment: `What if I want this result?` your id not matching on your question. little bit confusion please explain your scenario more

Comment: @prasanth I edited my question. You can find comments in the result that I want to achieve. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could do with [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to filter all `items` in single array.
2. Then recreate the array with `Array.reduce` and push the value based on `id` into new value object
3. And use `Array.filter` ignore the duplicate values on array
4. `Object.values` return only the value of object in array format

**Older**

```js
const arr = [ { id: 1, items: [ { id: 10, values: [11], }, { id: 20, values: [13, 14, 15], }, ], }, { id: 2, items: [ { id: 10, values: [12], }, { id: 20, values: [13, 15], }, ], }, ];


const res = Object.values(arr.flatMap(({items})=> items)
           .reduce((acc,{id,values})=>{
              acc[id] = acc[id] ?? {id,values:[]}; 
              //check the object exist or not 

              let newArr = acc[id]['values'].concat(values);
              let valArr = newArr.filter((v,i)=>newArr.indexOf(v) === i)
              //remove the duplicates

              acc[id]['values'] = valArr
             return acc
          },{}))

console.log(res)
```

**Updated**

```js
const arr = [ { id: 1, items: [ { id: 10, values: [11], }, { id: 20, values: [13, 14, 15], }, ], }, { id: 2, items: [ { id: 10, values: [12], }, { id: 20, values: [13, 15], }, ], }, ];


function filterMethod(arr,value,values){
return arr.map(({items})=> ({
              value:detector(items,value)[0],
              values:detector(items,values)
        }))
}

function detector(items,idVal){
  let ind = items.findIndex(({id})=> id === idVal);
  return ind > -1 ? items[ind]['values'] : ['']
}
         
console.log(filterMethod(arr,10,20))
```

Comment: if you want faster code try the following:




let res = [];
let map = new Map();

arr.flatMap(el => el.items).forEach(el => {
    map.set(el.id, map.get(el.id) ? [...map.get(el.id), ...el.values] : el.values);
});
map.forEach((value, key) => {
    res.push({
        id: key,
        values: value.filter(function(item, pos) {
            return value.indexOf(item) == pos;
        })
    });
})

Comment: @moustafa Nice., please post as answer instead of commenting. And also you are using more no of `forEach` loop. i don't know the speed difference on both. May i know how?

Comment: @prasanth I edited the question I tried my best but I need help.

Comment: @marek8623 check my latest answer i have added filtered duplicate value

Comment: @prasanth Yes, but now I want to achieve different result and I do not know how to do it.

Comment: @marek8623 check my updated answer. auto pick based on id is not possible. so you pass the id of `value,values` as a param. `detector` function validate the id exist or not